# insert json response to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to import a specific element of a json(display_name element as shown below), to my database.

At first i am innitiating curl:

```
    ..curl connection parameters
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $response_data = curl_exec($curl);

    var_dump($response_data); //checking if response has data,it has: "{"sku":{"id":1234,"display_name":"Apple iPhone 8",..}
    curl_close($curl);
    if(!$response_data) {
    die('curl error is -' . curl_error($curl));

    $data = json_decode($response_data);

    foreach ($data as $product) {
        $displayname=$product->display_name;
        }
```

but nothing is stored and i dont have any errors:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO phones (name)
VALUES ('$displayname')";
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If you `var_dump` the `$product` can you see the display_name? Might be an issue with the data key in your JSON object

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the response, i added the code for errors still no luck.

Comment: @RichieHughes thanks for stopping by, yeah if i `var_dump` i can see the data.

Comment: @akalogiros Is the data key showing as well? Are you able to paste more code, might give us an idea if the problem is with the way your inserting the data or whether its data related :) - Also just a comment, the way it is at the moment, it'll only insert the last one in the foreach loop (unless you've got the insert in the foreach loop)

Comment: `foreach ($undecoded_data->data as $product)` ?

Comment: @RichieHughes By all means, code added.

Comment: You just set the data in foreach loop, next you need to write code to save that to database.

Answer (score 0):

All about this :

```
$displayname=$product['display_name'];
```

is not an `Object` is an `Array`